# Implementing Bootstrap Confidence Intervals into Matlab

Tags: matlab

I apologise if this is quite obvious to some however I have been trying to get my head around bootstraps for a few hours, and for something so simple I am really struggling.

I have a large data set, however it is not normally distributed and am trying to find the confidence levels, hence why I have turned to bootstraps. I want to apply the bootstrap to the fourth column of a data set, which I can do.

However I am having trouble with the bootci function itself

```
ci=bootci(10000, ..... , array;
```

I am having trouble implementing the function, as I don't fully understand what the 2nd part of the bootci function, denoted ....., does.

I have seen @mean implemented on other examples, I'm assuming this calculates the mean for each column and applies it to the function.

If anyone could confirm my thinking or explain the function to me it would be much appreciated!

I am also unsure about how to change the sample size, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Don't you mean [bootstrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29), not bootleg? And what measure are you trying to find confidence intervals for?

Comment: You are correct! Not sure how I mixed that up, edited the title.

Comment: Ok, so first things first. Forget the bootstrap. Describe what value you are trying to find.  E.g.: are you trying to find the mean of your distribution? the mode? the median? Once that is established, the bootstrap stuff can be explained much easier.

Comment: I'm trying to find the confidence intervals of the data set, I already have a value for the mean, however it is heavily weighted. I saw bootstrap as a way of finding an accurate result for the mean and confidence intervals.

Comment: So you want to find the mean of the distribution, and the confidence interval of that mean, right? Ok, I can work with that... *writes*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of the question:

```
ci = bootci(10000, @mean, X);
```

Will determine a 95% confidence interval of the mean of the dataset `X` using 10000 subsamples generated using random sampling with replacement from dataset `X`.

The second argument of the function `@mean` indicates that the function to apply to the subsamples is `mean`, and hence to calculate the confidence interval of the mean.  You could equally pass in `@std` to calculate a confidence interval on the standard deviation if you wanted, or pass in any other suitable function for that matter.

From what I have read in the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/bootci.html), it does not seem to be possible to directly control the size of the subsamples used by the `bootci` function.

Comment: This solved my issue to simply replacing mean with median gives you the well recognised ci of the median